# Break apart text in a two column page and place table

Tags: floats, positioning, two-column

Is it imposible to insert something like \newpage to break up the text and place a table ? 
i have tried several float control packages, \floatbarrier and so on nothing gives the desired result - unbelievable that something so simple should be that difficult

Breaking apart the text manually and placing a table at a specific location should be possible.

i want to force something like

[image]

using \usepackage{stfloats} and \usepackage{placeins} with a \FloatBarrier under the table results in whitespace

[image]

Comment: Do you want to stop two column, insert a figure and start two column again?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The effect with `\FloatBarrier` is what was expected, I'm afraid. Push the float code back in the document.

Comment: So.. This seems as serious downside to latex, i can't believe that there's no solution to this simple problem?

Comment: So in the end, the only way i could fix this was by shrinking the figur and use \usepackage{stfloats}

Answer (score 4):

The package `stfloats` allows to have bottom two column floats:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stfloats}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\kant[1-3]

\begin{figure*}[b]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth,height=4cm]{example-image}

\caption{A caption to this wonderful picture}
\end{figure*}

\kant[4-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks to Frank Mittelbach for having mentioned the package in his highly valuable article on TUGboat about floats (TUGboat, volume 35, 2014, n. 3).

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but the problem persists. Is it possible to set a barrier at a section ? latex moves the figure to the next page

Comment: @Strangelove The usual method such as `\FloatBarrier` from `placeins` should work. But beware that the float will probably be turned into a page float.

Comment: @Strangelove I can't understand what you mean, sorry.